# About strtroupper syntax in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

Please help me with this. I wrote this but nothing occurs. What are doing wrong?

```
$sText = preg_replace("#: (\w)#", ': ' . mb_strtoupper("$1"), $sText);
```

Comment: What is your expected output and what is $sText?

Comment: $sText is a bunch of text like: She says: "hello, how are you?".

Comment: My expected output is: She says: "Hello, how are you?

Answer (score 2):

What you need is [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php), so that you can have a callback function and there you can call the function for the matched string, e.g.

```
$sText = preg_replace_callback("#: (\w)#", function($m){
    return mb_strtoupper($m[1]);
}, $sText);
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I introduce this string: "hello: hello" and nothing happens. Should be transform to: "hello: Hello"

Comment: @EstebanGorupicz Wups, I accidentally put 2 delimiters on each side. Just reload and try the code again

Comment: @EstebanGorupicz Also if it should transform to: `hello: Hello` then you probably want to use a non-capturing group for your colon, e.g. `#(?: :\s)(\w)#`

Comment: Im sorry but I don't see it like you. Take a look to this printscreen: http://i60.tinypic.com/2ccrms2.jpg